# datastax solr dynamicField full-text search

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We've run into a problem with our Datastax Enterprise search workload. Our version is `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.9.791 | DSE 4.8.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]`. We have a cassandra schema for this table with a map collection `properties map<text, text>` and in the solr schema.xml we have `<dynamicField name="properties*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />`.

The problem is that we've inserted data incorrectly, without using the prefix as described [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchDynFlds.html). Is there a way to make this data searchable without losing all of the data that's already in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a whole blog post about it:

http://www.sestevez.com/brians-loader-unloader-for-search/

TL;DR you have to re-insert the data, but the post has a one liner on how to do it with cassandra-loader and awk.

Comment: In your blog, you warn about using collections for large amounts of data. How large is "large"? With `nodetool cfstats` I see `Space used (total): 83112983` which doesn't seem too large.

Comment: as I think about it, what are some reasonable alternatives, avoiding map collections, to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Large as in too many vales in a map. Not total size. I'd aim for 10s